# A requisição do cURL no php resolve localmente um subdomínio?

Tags: php, libcurl

Tenho um servidor com VPS Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty e gostaria de saber se a utilização da biblioteca cURL resolve o DNS localmente para um subdomínio.

Tenho 2 domínios no mesmo server sendo que 1 é um subdomínio (Webservice).

Fazendo uma chamada de cURL ao webservice o mesmo será resolvido local ou ele passará pela internet?

Se passar pelas internet como faço para resolver ele localmente?

(Estou avaliando isso pois creio que resolver localmente irá diminuir o tempo da requisição)

Comment: Acho que não amigo.

Comment: Se o problema for que o endereço está sendo resolvido mais lentamente do que deveria, [tente usar `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL, 1);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php#104597).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você tem permissões de root, você pode entrar via SSH e fazer algo tipo

```
# echo '0.0.0.0 example.net' >> /etc/hosts
```

(naturalmente, trocando o IP e o domínio pelos valores apropriados)

A menos que o cURL faça algo *muito* criativo com a resolução de DNS, isso deve fazer o cURL (e todos os aplicativos do seu servidor) resolverem o domínio pro IP que você especificar.

Comment: Como eu coloco isso nisso: $curl = curl_init("http://mydomain.com/service-test/get_client");

Comment: Essa é minha dúvida.